# Overflow in 2's complement addition

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation

Consider 3_bit wide number system. Then range is between -4 to +3. We are going to perform subtraction +3-(-4). We know that result is +7 that dows not fit range. So sonething is wrong. We expect that hardware will alarm there is mistake because of overflow. Hardware uses XOR operation between carry to/from MSB. If XOR=1 there is overflow. In my example hardware cannot detect overflow. Where is the mistake?? I have shown operation in picture. +3 and -4 are true operands since they are in the range. Hardware only gets 2's complement of subtrahend when operation is subtraction and add it to the minuend. Finally XOR determines if there is overflow or not.!

Comment: `I have shown operation in picture` There is no picture. Also, I'm afraid your question is off-topic since it seems to be about a piece of hardware you designed yourself. Stackoverflow is for programming, not for hardware-design. Anyways, at the moment we have nothing to work with. If you can write down your (hardware) implementation as a short C function such that we can reproduce your problem we could try to help.

Comment: Taking the 2's complement of -4 already has the overflow, using the same XOR rule as usual. Also I don't think negating the subtrahend is common practice (since that's two additions), you would more likely invert it and then set the carry-in on the addition

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. Website did not allow me to upload picture because I am fresh here. Hardware uses XOR operation to detect occurrence of overflow. It XORs carry in and carry out at the MSB. How can hardware detect taking  2's complement of -4 is done? I know that this problem arises when we are taking 2's complement of -4. Hardware performs it by XORing subtrahend and carry in that enters the LSB of ripple adder.

Comment: "Taking the 2's complement of -4 already has the overflow," How can hardware detect it??

Comment: `-b = ~b + 1`, it's that addition that has the overflow, however explicitly negating the subtrahend is a strange implementation. If you implement subtraction as `a + ~b + 1` (single addition, using carry-in) then it works as normal. You can see that `~b + 1` (aka `-b`) is a subexpression, but it is done as part of the main addition.

Comment: Hi Harold, So many thanks for your excellent response. It shows that you have deeply understood fundamentals of digital design.